# Compiler Directive IF and IFEND

Tags: delphi

I have a project group containing three projects (two exe and one dll). Now, in one unit which is shared by the two exe-projects, I want to compile a specific region ONLY when in a specific project. How can I achieve this? Should I do something like this?

```
{$IF PROJECT1}
// Compile this code
{$IFEND}
```

I have never used Delphi compiler directives before.

Comment: What exactly is the question? Your question appears to contain the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Compiler directives](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE3/en/Delphi_compiler_directives) are defined at the project level (Project > Options > Delphi Compiler > Compiling), so as long as you do define the directive, it should work as you describe.

Comment: Thanks, so i think i got the hang of it, :D

I did what you said, added... lets say "PROJECT1" (In that dialog), then i used $IFDEF.

Comment: Note that if two projects share a compiled unit, you will need to be careful to rebuild each project when switching between them. Changing a compiler define will not be enough for the compiler to know that it needs to recompile that unit from source in order to apply the new compiler defines. It would be best if the projects did not share the DCU, but shared only the .pas source file and output the .dcu to project-local directories.